# How do I find the total number defined inputs in an array

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have an array of data that holds questions and answers

array

```
 "civilWorks": [
    { 
      question: 'Question 1?',
      radio_compliant_name: 'radcomp_question1',
      radio_compliant_input: 'my answer',  // one answer only
      id: 'question1'       
    },

    { 
      question: 'Question 2?',
      radio_compliant_name: 'radcomp_question2',
      radio_compliant_input: '', // undefined not answered
      id: 'question2'    
    }
  ]
```

Using the method below I can get the total number of questions no problem.  What I am trying to figure out is how I get the total number of radio_compliant_input entries that have been answered.  This way I will have number of total questions and number of answered questions.

.ts

```
getForm() {
  this.storage.get('test').then((val) => {
    this.auditResults = JSON.parse(val);
    this.form = this.auditResults.civilWorks;  
    console.log('form', this.form);  // shows array of form civilWorks
    console.log('form length', this.form.length); // gets total number of questions
    this.answer = this.auditResults.civilWorks.radio_compliant_input;  // in here I want to get the total answered
    console.log('total answered', this.answer);
  });
}
```

I fail at the 7 line this.answer.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your results are in this.auditResults.civilWorks, then you can user filter

```
this.answer = this.auditResults.civilWorks.filter(c => !!c.radio_compliant_input).length
```

Comment: I receive a 0 even though question 1 has been answered

Comment: can you show in console the this.auditResults.civilWorks?

Comment: My mistake you code works.  I didn't pull the entry properly